# Slot doesnt exist in connect function in C++/Qt project? (already reran make)

Tags: c++, qt

I am adding a slider bar to easyPaint, which will enable a zoom function.
I have the slider appearing where I want it on the screen, and the function I built for it shouldn't have any issues, but when I run it, I get a runtime error that the slot doesn't exist, when it clearly does.
I have already tried cleaning the solution, rerunning CMake, and rebuilding, and still get the "slot does not exist" error every time.
Can anyone else think of any other reason why I would get this issue?

Here is the setup of the dock with slider, within the mainwindow class:

```
dock = new QDockWidget(tr("Zoom"));
slider = new QSlider(dock);
addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea, dock);
dock->setWidget(slider);
dock->setFeatures(QDockWidget::NoDockWidgetFeatures);
slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setMinimum(0);
slider->setMaximum(16);
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(zoomBarAct(slider->value())));
```

Here is the zoom function, which I have declared within the private slots section in the header file:

```
void MainWindow::zoomBarAct(int zoom)
{
    float factor = static_cast<float>(zoom) / 4;
    getCurrentImageArea()->zoomImage(factor);
    getCurrentImageArea()->setZoomFactor(factor);
}
```

edit for function declaration (other functions after private slots omitted):

```
private slots:
     void zoomBarAct(int zoom);
```

Comment: Where's the function declaration? Also, [use the "new" signals slots syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) so you'll get a compile time error instead of a runtime error.

Comment: `SLOT(zoomBarAct(int))` See Nikos answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
SLOT(zoomBarAct(slider->value()))
```

doesn't make sense. You need to specify the name of the slot:

```
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(zoomBarAct(int));
```

However, you are using Qt4-style signal/slot connections. If you switch to modern, Qt5-style syntax, these errors will be caught at compile time. Use this instead, which is much safer and guaranteed to never produce these types of runtime errors, since everything is checked during compilation:

```
connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::zoomBarAct);
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try, but according to the Qt documentation, QSlider::valueChanged has a void return type. If I just put 'int', instead of the value 'slider->value()' in the zoomBarAct call, how does the parameter get passed to zoomBarAct?

Comment: @Chris The signal itself will call your slot and it will pass the correct value.

Comment: Parameters given to the signal are passed as parameters to the slot. Emitting the signal is basically same as calling the slot (either immediately or later from event loop depending on connection type). Signals don't support return values (even if slot method has return value).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The fix worked, and my zoom works fine now. I appreciate the help everyone.

Comment: @Chris By the way, if you intent to convert all your current connections to the new syntax (which I recommend) and you're using Qt Creator, you can right-click on the `connect` function call and select "Convert to Qt5".